# Hide tr based on inner style using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Hide my `tr` based on my `inner style`. Its having only inner styles.

Here i want to hide only one `tr`. which is having only `25px`.

```
<tr style="height: 40px;">
   <th></th>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 45px;">
     <th></th>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 25px;">
     <th class="k-scheduler-times-all-day">all day</th>
</tr>
```

I'm bit confused here. How do i hide my `tr`? Its not having any `id` and `class`.

Comment: which row you want to hide?

Comment: I don't want to loop each row of my table. If its having 1000 rows. then it will cause an performance hit.

Comment: also u can use tr:last{display:none;}

Comment: @RJK: Setting visual properties based on the concrete value of another visual property is a *very bad* idea. When you change the height of the cell, the other solition will break. You should definitely add a class to the affected rows.

Comment: @YatinMistry I'm not creating the `tr` its dynamic from third party control. So i can't see /define `id and class` until its rendered in browser.

Comment: @RJK just see it is lxg not me

Comment: @YatinMistry you asked this question `why are you not giving class or id?` so i replied now :)

Comment: @RJK You have already replied to me on that. i agree with that.

Comment: @lxg yes if i do that in Jquery also condition will get fail. if height got changed. i will try add a class. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RJK: I have downvoted the post because I feel that it lacks research effort, I think that it should be possible to find the answer with some googling. (Especially for somebody with almost 2000 rep.)

Comment: Its okay. I have googled before asking here. I did't found relevant solution. So asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr[style="height: 25px;"] {   
  display: none;  
}
```

And avoid to use jQuery for things that CSS can do.

Comment: I agree that CSS should be prefered over JS when possible, but this solution is very unflexible. What if the height changes by some pixels? A better solution would be based on `nth-child`.

Comment: The question was `hide tr based on inner style`. `nth` child is not inner style and it's unflexible as well because the number of trs can change too.

Comment: may i know the reason for down vote? Since i feel question is valid and correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Mytable tr').each(function(){    //loop through all the tr in table
  if($(this).css('height') == '25px')  //get a specific tr which satisfy condition
    $(this).hide();  //hide the row
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jjLsavo1/)

Comment: Could you please explain a bit why and how this is the solution?

Comment: @lxg..sorry i didn't get you..i have posted fiddle link also you can see it.

Comment: You answer was/is flagged as “low quality” in the review queue. I think that somebody had the feeling that it needs more context. (a JSfiddle is nice, but it's an off-site link, which is considered not to be sufficient as explaination.) Hope that helps.

Comment: Although I must say that all answers on this page are a bit cheap. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will hide all table rows with with a height of 25 pixels:

```
$('tr').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).height() == 25;
}).hide();
```